# this is my assignment but i dont know what i did wrong

Tags: linux, centos, symlink, lamp

This is a part of my assignment:

Create a directory named `members` inside the folder `/var/www/html`. For each member of either `executive-staff` or `management-staff`, create a folder inside the new directory, `members`, with the same name as the academic’s username (not their full name).

Inside each of these users’ home directories, create a symbolic link named `www` to their folder in `/var/www/html/members`.

For example, for the user `mraffone`, the script should create the following symbolic link:

```sh
$HOME/mraffone/www → /var/www/html/members/mraffone
```

Each new folder should have a default file, `index.html`, with the following text:

> “This is ’s personal space”,

where `<user>` should be replaced with the appropriate username.

For example, when visiting the URL `http://localhost:8080/members/mraffone`, you should see the text `“This ismraffone’s personal space.”` This file should only be readable and writable by the appropriate user.

Change the permissions of the file `index.php` so that it can only be changed by the user mraffone.

I did write this:

```sh
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/members
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/members/mraffone
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/members/tknight
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/members/willwaite

sudo ln -s /home/mraffone/8080/ /var/www
sudo ln -s /home/tknight/8080/ /var/www
sudo ln -s /home/willwaite/8080/ /var/www

sudo echo "this is mraffone's personal space." > /var/www/html/members/mraffone/www/index.html
sudo echo "this is tknight's personal space." > /var/www/html/members/tknight/www/index.html
sudo echo "this is willwaite's personal space." > /var/www/html/members/willwaite/www/index.html
```

but after running, I get the following error:

[image: error message after i run the script]

I got some advice but not enough for my question. I am wondering if any one can help me with that, please?

Comment: The screenshot that you posted does not contain an error

Comment: thank u for replay and sorry for my mistake because I placed the wrong picture, also when I am going on to this page : localhost:8080/members/mraffone on web site, there is no symlink for this user and obviously the message I tried to (echo) does not appear? –